# get data from one dropdown into second dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, html-select

I have two dropdown boxes, one is hided from users and second one is shown with some data from previous...
So I want to search data in the first dropdown and fill those data into the second..

now I have second code for first dropdown:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#medik_name').keyup(function () {
//  console.log( $(this).val() );

var valThis = this.value.toLowerCase(),
    lenght  = this.value.length;

if ( $(this).val().length >= 3 )
{

    $("#medik_list_all>option").each(function(){
//      console.log( $(this).val().length );

        var text  = $(this).text(),
            textL = text.toLowerCase(),
            htmlR = '<b>' + text.substr(0, lenght) + '</b>' + text.substr(lenght);

        (textL.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).html(htmlR).removeAttr('disabled').show() : $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();

    });

}
```

});

});

i.e first dropdown:

```
<select id='first_select'>
 <option value='1'>test1</option>
 <option value='2'>test2</option>
 <option value='3'>test3</option>
 <option value='..'>...</option>
</select>
```

second one:

```
<select id='second_select'>
</select>
```

and search input:

```
<input type='text'></input>
```

in which I type for example `tes`, so I want all options which contains `tes` to be in second dropdown...

So how I can do it?

Comment: Why do you need first dropdown if it is hidden?

Comment: where do `$('#medik_name')` and `$("#medik_list_all")` come from?

Comment: @Mark it's first and second dropdown